# how do i set an empty value if i don't fill image with file type lest the type is not null

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, dio, imagepicker

when I don't want to include the image value of an image of type File but I always get null, even if I have added null safety to the variable, so I can post the value to to api, so in conclusion I want to make the image file optional if I do not fill in the image, here's my code

```
Future postUpdateDataAdmin(
  String id,
  String fullName,
  String telp,
  String email,
  String address,
  File? photoImg,
) async {
  String? fileName = photoImg?.path.split('/').last;
  FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
    'photo' : await MultipartFile.fromFile(photoImg!.path, filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')),
    'full_name': fullName,
    'telp': telp,
    'email': email,
    'address': address,
  });

  try {
    var response =
        await Dio().post("${Api.baseUrl}/user/admin/updateData/$id",
            options: Options(
              followRedirects: false,
              // will not throw errors
              validateStatus: (status) => true,
            ),
            data: data);
    if (response.data["status"] == true) {
      print('test posttt asdasd as ${response.data['status']}');
      return response.data['data'];
    } else {
      return throw Exception("Tidak Dapat Mengambil Data");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    print('kenapa ?$error');
  }
}
```

And this is how pick image

```
Future _pickImage(source) async {
  try {
    XFile image = await imagePicker.pickImage(
        source: source,
        imageQuality: 50,
        preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front);
    if(image==null)return;
    setState(() {
      fileImage = File(image.path);
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

And this is how i call the Service on button

```
onTap: () async {
  await ServiceAdminUnit().postUpdateDataAdmin(
    '9708',
    controller.fullNameCont.text,
    controller.telephoneCont.text,
    controller.emailCont.text,
    controller.addressCont.text,
    controller.fileImage,
  );
},
```

if I empty the image it will raise an error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2zdx.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a null check before using `!`. And if it is null, then return from the function

```dart
  String? fileName = photoImg?.path.split('/').last;
  if (fileName == null) return;
  FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
    'photo': await MultipartFile.fromFile(photoImg.path,..
```

Or to set default empty string

```dart
String fileName = photoImg?.path.split('/').last?? "";
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question, but the main point of my question is not that, my main point is how i post image to api with null value, because i want make optional edit for my image picker, cause the value from my image picker

Comment: you like to post null value to the server?

Comment: @AhmadMiqdad, hey I am stuck in same problem, did u solve this?? if u did can u share the solution??

Comment: @Mr.Robot yeah i have to solve this problem, so when you want make optional value fill, you can use ternary operator when u upload to a server in service, like this
`'photo': photoImg == null
          ? ''
          : await MultipartFile.fromFile(photoImg.path,
              filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')),`